# Ultrasound Receiver

Tags: arduino, sensor, ultrasound

[image]

This is a receiving part of an ultrasound transducer using an NDT ultrasound probe.

The overall idea of the circuit is this: the ultrasound received from a patient is very low-voltage so the 3-stage amplifier amplifies it to a higher voltage and sends it to an Arduino.

Can anybody help me find out what is then needed of each component and process in each stage?

Why are a rectifier and a peak detector used, and how can we visualise a blood vessel using this?

For reference: [Body-ultrasound Sonography With Arduino](https://www.instructables.com/Body-ultrasound-Sonography-With-Arduino/) on Instructables.

Comment: Why is shorted to ground the input of LM7171 ?

Answer (score 1):

The ultrasound transducers used in [the project you referred to](https://www.instructables.com/Body-ultrasound-Sonography-With-Arduino/) operate at 5MHz.  The sampling rate of the Arduino Due is a maximum of 1MHz - if using the Arduino libraries, it is probably lower.

You can't directly sample the 5MHz signal from the ultrasound transducer with just the Arduino ADC.  The circuit provides you with the peak value of the ultrasound signal.  The peak detector holds the level long enough for the Arduino ADC to properly read it.

The linked Arduino software is essentially averaging 100 readings, so the output speed will be far lower than the ADC sampling rate.

---

Visualizing a blood vessel with that setup will probably be very difficult.    It will do to see how such a system works, and it will probably let you detect the difference between bones and soft tissue.  If you run the detector across your body in a place where there's a known blood vessel, you'll probably be able to see a difference in the values - the image will change somewhat.

You will **not** get a picture out of it like you get from a commercial ultrasound system.

The instructable project sends a straight beam out and detects a reflection from that.  The software simply averages a bunch of such measurements to show you a relative "strong reflection" or "weak reflection."  You would need a time and an intensity measurement for each point, as well as a way to detect the sensor position in order to make a scan like a commercial ultrasound machine.

You can extend that project somewhat to improve it, but it will not ever be able to make pictures like a commercial ultrasound machine.

Comment: Can I get differentiate blood clot and normal blood flow in vein in hands?

Comment: You can't detect blood flow with this setup.

Comment: Is there any uttrasound receiver transmitter and recmodule available in market to pulsate 5MHz probe?